# How to import shell functions from one file into another?

Tags: function, shell, import

I have the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD=$(lsb_release -sd | sed 's/"//g')
export ARCH=$(uname -m)
export VER=$(lsb_release -sr)

# Load the test function
/bin/bash -c "lib/test.sh"

echo $VER
DISTROS=('Arch'
'CentOS'
'Debian'
'Fedora'
'Gentoo')
for I in "${DISTROS[@]}"
do
  i=$(echo $I | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') # convert distro string to lowercase
  if [[ $LD == "$I"* ]]; then
    ./$ARCH/${i}.sh
  fi
done
```

As you can see it should run a shell script, depending on which architecture and OS it is run on. It should first run the script `lib/test.sh` before it runs this architecture and OS-specific script. This is `lib/test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function comex {
  which $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

and when I run it on x86_64 Arch Linux with this `x86_64/arch.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if comex atom; then
  printf "Atom is already installed!"
elif comex git; then
  printf "Git is installed!"
fi
```

it returned the output:

```
rolling
./x86_64/arch.sh: line 3: comex: command not found
./x86_64/arch.sh: line 5: comex: command not found
```

so clearly the `comex` shell function is not correctly loaded by the time the `x86_64/arch.sh` script is run. Hence I am confused and wondering what I need to do in order to correctly define the `comex` function such that it is correctly loaded in this architecture- and OS-dependent final script.

I have already tried using `. "lib/test.sh"` instead of `/bin/bash -c "lib/test.sh"` and I received the exact same error. I have also tried adding `. "lib/test.sh"` to the loop, just before the `./$ARCH/${i}.sh` line. This too failed, returning the same error.

Comment: `. lib/test.sh`, I believe.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Brief answer: you need to import your functions using `.` or `source` instead of `bash -c`:

```
# Load the test function
source "lib/test.sh"
```

Longer answer: when you call script with `bash -c`, a child process is created. This child process sees all exported variables (including functions) from parent process. But not vice versa. So, your script will never see `comex` function. Instead you need to include script code directly in current script and you do so by using `.` or `source` commands.

---

Part 2. After you "sourced" `lib/test.sh`, your main script is able to use `comex` function. But arch scripts won't see this function because it is not exported to them. Your need to `export -f comex`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function comex {
  which $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
}
export -f comex
```

Comment: Should have said in my original question I had already tried using `.`, just tried your exact suggestion (with the `source`) and it too returned: `rolling
./x86_64/arch.sh: line 3: comex: command not found
./x86_64/arch.sh: line 5: comex: command not found`

Comment: Adding `export comex` to the end of the `lib/test.sh` script made no difference. Nor did adding `export comex` to the main script, after the `source "lib/test.sh"` line.  Plus the function name is `comex` (short for "command exist").

Comment: Lets debug it piece by piece. After you sourced and exported function, does your _main_ script sees this function?

Comment: Sure does. I just added `comex pi` after the sourcing line and it recognized it.

Comment: My bad. Functions are exported with `export -f`.

Comment: Yes, either export the function with `export -f`, or alternately, source the arch  function `. ./$ARCH/${i}.sh` so that it is not in a subprocess.

Comment: @gudok - Is it "necessary" to place the `source importedScript.sh` at the beginning of the script (right after the `#!/bin/bash`) or is it arbitrary? In case of the later situation - is there any convention where it should be placed ?

Comment: @GuyAvraham - you can place `source importedScript.sh` anywhere (but of course it must be done before the functions from this script are used).